# Qt: Tab Icon when QDockWidget becomes docked

Tags: qt, icons, tabbar, qdockwidget

Qt's QMainWindow has a ability to dock windows derived from QDockWidget. It also would put one on top on the other if few of them are stacked, producing a tab bar. Whenever a QDockWidget's state changes a signal topLevelChanged() is emmitted. At this point I would like to get access to underlying QTabWidget to set an icon for a a newly added tab. How can I do it? My patience is over trying to dig the answer out from Qt's documentation and source code. Thank you in advance.

[image]

So icon I want to be on Contents/Index tabs.

Comment: very difficult to visualize. Could you please post some sort of UI

Comment: qTabWidget->setStyleSheet("QTabBar::tab,QTabBar::tab:selected {background-image : url(:path);}");

Comment: qTabWidget ? First I have to somehow get it...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Once at least one dockwidget has been tabified, the main-window will create a `QTabBar` to provide the dock-tabs. Each dock-area can have its own tab-bar. These tab-bars will become children of the main-window, so you can use [findChildren()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qobject.html#findChildren) or [children()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qobject.html#children) to get references to them.

The main difficulty will be in finding which dock-widget belongs to which tab and in which tab-bar. If the dock-widget window-titles are all unique, you can just search using the [tabText()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtabbar.html#tabText). Otherwise, you might be able to use the [tabData()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtabbar.html#tabData), which Qt sets internally to a `quintptr` from the dock-widget.

Once you have the correct tab, you can of course use [setTabIcon()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtabbar.html#setTabIcon) to add your icon. But note that every time a dock-widget is untabified or moved to another tab-bar, the icon will be lost.

Comment: It worked, but there is another cosmetic problem. If there is a single docked widget and I drag another one over it (but not yet have it dropped), The Qt animation takes effect and a tab bar is created at this moment (with one tab). And the single tab has no icon. When I drop, only the second tab gets an icon. Maybe topLevelChanged() signal is not good for this. It would be nice to have hooked a tab bar creation procedure

Comment: @def. Maybe you could override main-window `event()` and watch for [child events](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qchildevent.html) to see when the tab-bars are added.

Comment: Not a problem, I just run through all tab bars during initialization and every time whenever docking layout changes.

Comment: @def. So is everything working now? If so, I would be grateful if you accepted my answer (assuming you found it useful).